# SQLite: How to reduce byte size of integer values?

Tags: sqlite, optimization, types, integer, sqldatatypes

I have a SQLite table (without row ID, but that's probably irrelevant, and without any indexes) where my rows contain the following data:

- 2 real values, one of which is the primary key
- 3 integers < 100
- 1 more field for integers, but currently always null

According to http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html, integer values can take 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 or 8 bytes according to their magnitude. Therefore I'd expect each row in my table to take up about 20 bytes. In reality, `sqlite3_analyzer` gives me for the table

```
Average payload per entry......................... 25.65     
Maximum payload per entry......................... 26
```

which is somewhere in between the minimum value of 20 and the maximum of 32 (if all integers were stored with 4 bytes). Is it possible to give the DB a "hint" to use even smaller integer types wherever possible? Or how else can the discrepancy be explained? (I don't think it's indexes because there are none for this table.)

Similarly, on a previous table I had 2 real values + 2 small integers and each entry occupied slightly more than 24 bytes (which is also more than I would have expected).

Also, there is no way to store floats in single precision with SQLite right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format) has one integer for the header size, one integer for each column to describe the value's type, and all the data of the column values.

In this case, we have:

```
bytes
1     header size
6     column types
16    two real values
3     three small integers between 2 and 127
0     NULL
--
26
```

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!